# Why Phone Number validate without regEx giving dead code in java

Tags: java, loops, validation, if-statement

index increment showing dead code why so ?? before adding special character condition it was working fine no dead code was showing and i want to validate special character condition as well.

```
public class ValidatePhoneNumber {

void validatePhoneNumber(String pNumber) {

    // 1st Case - +91 9765463742 have to check for + sign
    boolean flag = false;
    String specialCharacter = "!@#$%^&*()-/`~:<>/?|=.,";
    if (pNumber.startsWith("+") && pNumber.length() == 14) {

        for (int index = 1; index < pNumber.length(); index++) {
            if ((Character.isDigit((pNumber.charAt(index))) || Character.isSpaceChar((pNumber.charAt(index))))
                        && (!(specialCharacter.contains(Character.toString(pNumber.charAt(index)))))
                            && (!(Character.isLetter(pNumber.charAt(index))))) {
        
                flag = true;
            }
             else
                System.out.println(pNumber.charAt(index) + " " + pNumber + " Number is Invalid");
            flag = false;
            break;
        }
        if (flag == true) {
            System.out.println("Number " + pNumber + " is Valid");
        }
    }


public static void main(String[] args) {
    ValidatePhoneNumber phoneNumber = new ValidatePhoneNumber();
    phoneNumber.validatePhoneNumber("+91 975644@742");
    phoneNumber.validatePhoneNumber("09765463742");
```

Comment: Because you `break` immediately after the first iteration, so `index++` can never be reached.

Comment: @QBrute if i removing `break` firstly shows invalid but in next iteration flag become true and shows number is valid.

Comment: Then you simply missed the curly braces around `else`. I assume the break belongs to that

Comment: @QBrute Thanks for swift response its resolved now

Comment: Why not just check if each char is a digit or a space? The extra checks (special character or letter) seem superfluous.

Comment: Hey @johnnyMopp nice suggestion i'll try this

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because of the following `break` statement which will break the `for` loop right after the first iteration and therefore `index++` will never get an opportunity to run:

```
else
    System.out.println(pNumber.charAt(index) + " " + pNumber + " Number is Invalid");
flag = false;
break;
```

You should write it as:

```
void validatePhoneNumber(String pNumber) {
    // 1st Case - +91 9765463742 have to check for + sign
    boolean flag = false;
    int index;
    String specialCharacter = "!@#$%^&*()-/`~:<>/?|=.,";
    if (pNumber.startsWith("+") && pNumber.length() == 14) {
        for (index = 1; index < pNumber.length(); index++) {
            if (!(Character.isDigit(pNumber.charAt(index)) || Character.isSpaceChar(pNumber.charAt(index)))
                    && (specialCharacter.contains(Character.toString(pNumber.charAt(index)))
                            || Character.isLetter(pNumber.charAt(index)))) {
                flag = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    } else {
        flag = true;
    }
    if (!flag) {
        System.out.println("Number " + pNumber + " is Valid");
    } else {
        System.out.println(pNumber + " Number is Invalid");
    }
}
```

Note that I've moved `System.out.println(pNumber.charAt(index) + " " + pNumber + " Number is Invalid");` out of the loop so that this message gets printed only once.

**Test code:**

```
ValidatePhoneNumber phoneNumber = new ValidatePhoneNumber();
phoneNumber.validatePhoneNumber("+91 975644@742");
phoneNumber.validatePhoneNumber("+91 9765463742");
```

**Output:**

```
+91 975644@742 Number is Invalid
Number +91 9765463742 is Valid
```